# IPV6 address to array of uint64_t is not working as expected

Tags: c, networking, ipv6

I am trying to convert an IPv6 address in string format to array  of uint64_t data. For this i have written below program

```
typedef struct
    {
        union
        {struct in6_addr  sa;
        uint64_t addr[2];
        }u;
    } ipv6_addr_t;

    ipv6_addr_t  rnc;
    char rncs[100] = "2000::200a";
    inet_pton(AF_INET6, rncs, &(rnc.u.sa));
    printf("%u\", rnc.u.addr[0]);
```

> Expected output is 1st 64 bits of the address which will be **2^61 =
>   2305843009213693952.**
>
> But when i execute the program i am getting output as **32** which is the 
>   first byte of the address.

I am not understanding the reason behind it , please help. Thanks!

Comment: A `struct in6_addr` has control information at the start of the structure before the actual data bytes holding the address.  Take a look at its size; it won’t be 16 bytes.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I think you're thinking about a `struct sockaddr_in6`.  According to [the manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ipv6.7.html), a `struct in6_addr` is just a wrapper for an array of `unsigned char`.

Comment: `%u` is likely to be the wrong printf format specifier to print a `uint64_t`. Use the `PRIu64` macro defined by `#include <inttypes.h>` to get the correct format specifier, e.g. `printf("%" PRIu64 " %"  PRIu64 "\n", rnc.u.addr[0], rnc.u.addr[1]);`. If you do not have `#include <inttypes.h>`, you could use `printf("%llu %llu\n", (unsigned long long)rnc.u.addr[0], (unsigned long long)rnc.u.addr[1]);` instead.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: there are reasons for making comments when answering from a cell phone. I was certainly thinking of the `sockaddr_in6` structure. I’ve not checked what, if anything, POSIX has to say on the topic.

Comment: Even after using PRIu64  output is still 32

Comment: I can't say I'm much surprised, @NiranjanUpadhya.  In fact, I predicted it in my answer, though I was still working on that when you posted your observation.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, it turns out that [POSIX is less specific about `struct in6_addr`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/netinet_in.h.html) than the Linux manual is.  It requires a member that is an array of 16 `int8_t`, but not that it be only or first member.  That, then, is another flaw in the OP's code.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: yup — I was noticing that in the [`<netinet/in.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/netinet_in.h.html) specification.  As you've noticed, it says: _The `<netinet/in.h>` header shall define the `in6_addr` structure, which shall include at least the following member: `uint8_t s6_addr[16]`  This array is used to contain a 128-bit IPv6 address, stored in network byte order._  Given that it is stored in network byte order, it would be best to print it out using pairs of hex digits with 0-compression if appropriate.  I suppose there is a function to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several problems here.

- your method for printing the result is inherently flawed.  The `printf` directive `%u` is not generically for printing unsigned integers, but rather specifically for printing values of type `unsigned int`.  Although it is possible that your `int64_t` is the same type as `unsigned int`, that would be atypical.  If they are not the same type, then the mismatch between directive and actual argument result in undefined behavior. @AndrewHenle explains in his answer how to print an `int64_t` via `printf`.
- By using a `union` to map the bytes of your `struct in6_addr` onto an array of `int64_t`, you are exposing yourself to the details of the byte ordering of your implementation's representation of `int64_t`.  That you can present a specific expected result at all indicates that you are assuming a particular representation (and evidently one that does not match your system).
- You seem to think that fewer bytes are printed than should be, but even if you corrected your `printf` format per Andrew's answer, I'm inclined to think that the output would be the same.  You observe that the value that is printed corresponds to the first byte of the address, but think about what the next several bytes are: all zeroes, until you get to the final two.  Now consider a bit pattern consisting of one byte having the value 32 (decimal), followed by seven bytes with value zero.  If you interpret that pattern as a 64-bit, unsigned, little-endian integer, its value is 32.  That's the most likely thing for the corrected code to print on an Intel-based machine.

Evidently you want to produce `int64_t` values whose *logical* bit patterns match the address bits.  You have instead produced values whose *physical* bit patterns match the address bits.  This is to be expected when you use a `union` instead of arithmetic to convert between byte array and integer.  I suggest using a loop instead:

```
struct in6_addr sa;
int64_t addr_ints[2] = { 0, 0 };
char rncs[100] = "2000::200a";
inet_pton(AF_INET6, rncs, &sa);

for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    addr_ints[i / 8] = addr_ints[i / 8] << 8 + sa.s6_addr[i];
}
printf( "%" PRIu64 "\n", addr_ints[ 0 ] );
```

That also avoids problems in the event that `struct in6_addr` is laid out differently than you seem to expect, as long as the layout conforms to POSIX.

Comment: Yes i was trying in Intel machine , now i tried the same in MIPS architecture machine which is big endian, and the output is 2305843009213693952.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to any problems noted in the comments, using the wrong `printf()` format specifier is undefined behavior.

Per **7.21.6 Formatted input/output functions**, paragraph 9 of [the C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> If  a  conversion  specification  is  invalid,  the  behavior  is 
>   undefined. If  any argument  is not  the  correct  type  for  the 
>   corresponding  conversion  specification,  the  behavior  is
>   undefined.

Given that

```
rnc.u.addr[0]
```

is a `uint64_t`, the `printf()` format specifier `%u` in

```
printf("%u\n", rnc.u.addr[0]);
```

is incorrect.

The proper format for a `uint64_t` is `PRIu64`:

```
printf( "%" PRIu64 "\n", rnc.u.addr[ 0 ] );
```

Note also your code, as posted, is not correct:

```
printf("%u\", rnc.u.addr[0]);
```

That's won't even compile - it's an unterminated string.  The second `"` char is escaped as `\"`.  I assume you meant `"%u\n"`.

Comment: Even after using PRIu64 output is still 32